# How does the hydrostatic paradox operate when a column of lighter liquid rests atop a “floor” of heavier liquid?

Tags: pressure, potential-energy, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

I know that, according to the hydrostatic paradox, the height of a homogeneous liquid is the only determinant of pressure within that homogeneous liquid, and the shape of its container does not affect that pressure. But I need to maximize the height of a lighter liquid atop a heavier liquid while minimizing the depth which the former sinks into the latter.

For illustration, posit a straight pipe of x inside diameter, open at both ends and extending vertically 20 feet above and 20 feet below a surface of liquid mercury. For simplicity, posit further a reservoir of mercury large enough to render irrelevant any amount by which mercury displaced from the pipe will raise the surface level of mercury outside the pipe. Add water to that pipe from above until water reaches the lip of the pipe and measure the depth of mercury displacement. If you now posit a non-uniform pipe with x inside diameter for 20 feet above the surface level of mercury outside the pipe, but now with 50x or 5x inside diameter for 20 feet below the surface level of mercury outside the pipe, then will filling that non-uniform pipe to the brim depress the surface level of mercury inside the pipe measurably less?

“Chemomechanics” offers a mathematical formula to opine that the uniform and nonuniform pipes will have the same mercury height. I can’t argue, much less prove, anything mathematically, which is why I’m here. But my empirical tests show that the mercury depression in the nonuniform pipe measures less than the mercury depression in the uniform pipe. And if the “Chemomechanics” analysis were correct, then wouldn’t a nonuniform pipe with inside diameter of 500x or 5,000x also depress a.k.a. displace exactly the same amount of mercury across an astonishingly huge area—quite the accomplishment for a little column of water?

Hopefully this edit of the original question will help reopen it.

Comment: Ignoring separate effects such as capillarity, the uniform and nonuniform pipes will have the same mercury height $h_\text{mercury}$; it's not clear why you claim otherwise. At the open bottom, the pressure must equal $\rho_\text{mercury}g(20\,\text{ft})$, so the mercury height in the pipe must satisfy $\rho_\text{water}(40\,\text{ft}-h_\text{mercury})+\rho_\text{mercury}h_\text{mercury}=\rho_\text{mercury}(20\,\text{ft})$ regardless of variations in the pipe diameter.

Comment: The pressure in a liquid column is the sum of $\rho g h$ for each separate liquid.  I don't understand how this is a paradox.

Comment: How did you do your experiment? What were the actual dimensions of the pipe?

Comment: I partially filled a container with mercury and mounted a vertical tube, then slowly added dyed water to the tube until it barely displaced enough mercury to leak out and float to the top, then marked the height of water in the tube. Next I mounted and sealed a percolator stem at the bottom of the tube and repeated the process. Water rose significantly higher before leaking out and up. Thank you for asking. My question originally asked about interplay between weight and pressure of a lighter liquid atop a denser liquid, hoping to extrapolate better from this crude test.